# Carriage return line feed causing operation to fail

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, csv, client

I am using the ConvertCsvToXML tool in my client application to send data to a webservice.
The seperator field is a comma however the last column in csv file is causing a problem.

The name exists with a carriage return line feed in it, how do I avoid this?

The line feed is - `"&#xD;"`

which after research I believe means a new line.

I tried adding it into the seperator fields -

`XDocument doc = ConvertCsvToXML(csv, new[] { ",", "&#xD;" });`

However this does not work, perhaps it doesn't allow multiple seperators however I do not know the parameters of the tool.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/ConvertCsvToXml.aspx (*why do we have to google that?)

```
XDocument doc = ConvertCsvToXML(csv, new[] { ",", "\n" });
```

Perhaps you need `\r` as well